# Where is the ejs download for browser support?

Tags: ejs

I followed the [instructions](https://ejs.co/) and downloaded the [build linked their](https://github.com/mde/ejs/releases/latest). After expanding the download I used `lib/ejs.js` which leads to **"ReferenceError: require is not defined"** errors. So, that's a node.js build not a browser build (?). Can't locate any browser build nor Google helps. So probably I'm complete off, but anyway, could someone enlighten me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [get started section on the docs](https://ejs.co/#install) under **Browser support**:

```js
let people = ["geddy", "neil", "alex"];
let html = ejs.render('<%= people.join(", "); %>', { people: people });

document.getElementById("root").insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", html);
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/mde/ejs/releases/download/v3.0.2/ejs.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/k-sav/pen/jOWdXBK)